# Can you zip all pairs in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

Suppose, just for a minute, then get back to your day, that I have two string domains in Chapel and I want to get a string domain of all pairs.

```
var dd: domain(string),  sd: domain(string);
dd += "Monday"; dd+="Tuesday"; dd+="Wednesday";
sd += "Rainy"; sd+= "Sunny";

var crossDomain = // 6 strings like "Monday-Rainy", "Monday-Sunny"
```

I can do nest `for` loops, but I'm wondering if there is a more succinct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think nested for or for loops are a fine bet:

```
for day in dd do
  for cond in sd do
    crossDomain += (day + "-" + cond);
```

An alternative would be to write an iterator to factor the loops away from the code:

```
for (day,cond) in allpairs(dd, sd) do
  crossDomain += (day + "-" + cond);

iter allpairs(d1, d2) {
  for i in d1 do
     for j in d2    do
      yield (i,j);
}
```

This requires slightly more code, but has the advantage that if you were to do this all-pairs pattern multiple times in your code, you could re-use the iterator multiple times.  Note that the iterator could also yield the concatenated strings directly if you preferred.

Comment: Trivia: Back in the day, Chapel had a "tensor iteration" mode that was a cousin to the current zippered (`zip()`) style of iteration.  This led to various semantic challenges without offering much benefit over having the user write such iterators themselves, as with `allpairs()` above, so it was ultimately removed from the language.